# Python: NameError: global name 'nt' is not defined

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

Guys i'm facing the error on my python code, i've trying many things and the error persist, how to solve?

The code was running many months in... and suddently stopped

The message error is ...

> global name 'nt' is not defined: NameError
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 35, in lambda_handler
>   nt("Lambda Function Name : " + context.function_name)
>   NameError: global name 'nt' is not defined

```
# Clients
sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
athena_client = boto3.client('athena')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    nt("Lambda Function Name : " + context.function_name)
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
```

...

Comment: Please edit your question to include a MWE. This will make it easier for others to reproduce your error and help answer the question.

 https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you mean `print` here? `nt("Lambda Function Name : " + context.function_name)`

Comment: in your first line of `lambda_handler` you have a line that reads `nt("Lambda Function Name : " + context.function_name)`. I'm pretty sure it should be `print("Lambda Function Name : " + context.function_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not nt its print

```
print("Lambda Function Name : " + context.function_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not know the function nt.
Maybe nt is a typo for print ? 
Like
print("Lambda Function Name : " + context.function_name)